# How to add a new column to dataframe based on conditions on another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

I have the following example dataframe:

```
d = {'col1': [4, 2, 8, 4, 3, 7, 6, 9, 3, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df


    col1
0   4
1   2
2   8
3   4
4   3
5   7
6   6
7   9
8   3
9   5
```

I need to add `col2` to this dataframe, and values of this new column will be set by comparing `col1` values (from different rows) as described below. Each row of `col2` will be set as following:

`df.loc[0, "col2"]` will say how many of `df.loc[1, "col1"]`, `df.loc[2, "col1"]` and `df.loc[3, "col1"]` are bigger than `df.loc[0, "col1"]`.

`df.loc[1, "col2"]` will say how many of `df.loc[2, "col1"]`, `df.loc[3, "col1"]` and `df.loc[4, "col1"]` are bigger than `df.loc[1, "col1"]`.

`df.loc[2, "col2"]` will say how many of `df.loc[3, "col1"]`, `df.loc[4, "col1"]` and `df.loc[5, "col1"]` are bigger than `df.loc[2, "col1"]`.

And so on...

If there are not `3 rows` left after the `index N`, `col2` value will be set to `-1`.

The end result will look like the following:

```
    col1    col2
0   4       1
1   2       3
2   8       0
3   4       2
4   3       3
5   7       1
6   6       1
7   9       -1
8   3       -1
9   5       -1
```

I need a function that will take a dataframe as input and will return the dataframe by adding the new column as described above.

In the example above, next 3 rows are considered. But this needs to be configurable and should be an input to the function that will do the work.

Speed is important here so it is not desired to use for loops.

How can this be done in the most efficient way in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a reversed [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html) to compare the values to the next ones:

```
N = 3
df['col2'] = (df.loc[::-1, 'col1']
                .rolling(N+1)
                .apply(lambda s: s.iloc[:-1].gt(s.iloc[-1]).sum())
                .fillna(-1, downcast='infer')
             )
```

Alternatively, using [`numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

N = 3
df['col2'] = np.r_[(df['col1'].to_numpy()[:-N, None]
                    < swv(df['col1'], N)[1:]  # broadcasted comparison
                    ).sum(axis=1),            # count True per row
                   -np.ones(N, dtype=int)]    # add missing -1
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2
0     4     1
1     2     3
2     8     0
3     4     2
4     3     3
5     7     1
6     6     1
7     9    -1
8     3    -1
9     5    -1
```

Comment: You're welcome @edn. If you have a large dataset, I'd be interested to have a feedback on the performance, I expect the numpy approach to be quite faster!

Comment: The environment where scripts are run is a bit complex and costly, so I may not try both approaches. Since you expect the second one to be faster, I will go for that first. If things go too slow, I will try the other one and write a comment here as well.

Comment: @mozway Why did you have to inverse the column in the pandas approach?

Comment: @alibakhtiari to perform the rolling in the correct order as rolling uses the **previous** rows (or centered, but not following)

Comment: @edn on your example numpy is 16x faster (160µs vs 2.6 ms), and >3x faster on a 1000x larger input (0.5s vs 1.8s)

Comment: A for loop in numba might not be bad. Plus if you pass raw = True in the rolling soon, perf might improve. Awesome solution as always